# Собственный репозиторий в maven

Tags: java, maven

Могу ли я создать свой репозиторий в maven, а потом подкачивать его в нужных мне проектах, подобно `PyPI` в `python` ? Если да, то как ?

Comment: да можно, есть несколько статьей, типа http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository

Comment: Вас интересует свой локальный репозиторий или репозиторий на серверах maven?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov Серверах maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Непосредственно на серверах maven см. [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)
2. На альтернативных серверах есть платные и бесплатные хостинги для репозиториев по формату совместимые с maven см. [mymavenrepo.com](https://mymavenrepo.com/), [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) ([тут](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/07/maven-repository-amazon-s3.html) инструкция), [JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/buy-now/#Cloud) и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Привет.

Я один из авторов [myMavenRepo.com](http://mymavenrepo.com). Мы постарались сделать максимально простой сервис для индивидуальных разработчиков / маленьких кампаний - можно создать репозиторий в облаке и настроить свой `pom.xml` / `build.gradle` за 5-10 минут.

Ну и наш небольшой вклад в java сообщество - бесплатный план, который подходит очень многим....

---

[добавил подробное описание]

> Если да, то как ?

1. Регистрируетесь
2. Мы вам высылаем подробное письмо с инструкциями.
3. По инструкции конфигурируете pom.xml / build.gradle
4. Загружаете артифакты / используете в проектах

Перед конфигуриррованием pom.xml / build.gradle нужно определиться со схемой доступа. Есть простая, но слабозащищенная (unique URL) и защищенная, но сложнее (http auth). В зависимости от схемы доступа - разная схема конфигурирования.

После того, как выбрали схему, можно начать конфигурировать pom.xml / build.gradle. Можно прочитать наши гайды, но лучше открыть проект, нажать на иконку (?) и получить подробные инструкции конкретно под данный проект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: реклама — это, наверно, хорошо. но здесь ещё принято что-то типа ответа давать.